# why does javascript need a jit

Tags: javascript, jit

why does javascript in the web browsers (firefox, chrome) need a jit?

I know that JIT makes the code run faster, but wouldn't an interpreter be fast enough since it's only for web pages?

Comment: Web pages, or web applications? Some of those "pages" crunch through a fair amount of data now, not to mention updating the server, presentation, and logic.

Comment: we now evolved to what we call  `web applications` from just `web pages` which consumes lot of resources and do more stuff than showing some content :)

Comment: `since it's only for web pages`? Web pages like ChromeOS?

Comment: Because someone had the bright idea that they could stuff a full application in a web page within a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an interpreter would be fast enough for anything that JavaScript was originally intended for.

However, there is competition to build the best browser, and a part of that is to have the fastest JavaScript engine. There wasn't a need for JavaScript to be that fast, it was working fine before, but we wanted it to work even better.

Now that we have fast JavaScript, we have developed bloated libraries that take advantage of the extra speed to allow you to think less about efficient ways of doing things. We have developed advanced web applications that is way beond what originally was intended for Javascript. We have created a need because we wanted to take advantage of what we had.

There simply isn't a reasonable way back to using just interpreters for JavaScript. It wouldn't fly in a world that expects JavaScript to be as fast as it is now.